# How to combine click with hover function in same status？

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to add click function but it doesn't run...

```
$("#menu2 li").hover(function() { //On hover... 

    $(this).find("span").stop().animate({ 
        marginTop: "-40" //Find the span tag and move it up 40 pixels 
    }, 250); 

    $("#menu2 li").click(function() { //On click... 
        $(this).find("span").stop().animate({ 
            marginTop: "-40" //Find the span tag and move it up 40 pixels 
        }, 250); } 
        , function() { //On hover out... 
            $(this).find("span").stop().animate({ 
                marginTop: "0" //Move the span back to its original state (0px) 
            }, 250); 
        }); 
});
```

here is the link:[after click, i hope it still be white color](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30777772/menu22.html)

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you want to do? Do you want to execute the same function that is executed for `mouseenter` (hover) on a `click`  ?

Comment: when click the menu,click function is same like hover.how to combinen it?

Comment: okay...I try to add click function,but is dosent run.

Comment: $("#menu2 li").hover(function() { //On hover...
  $(this).find("span").stop().animate({ 
   marginTop: "-40" //Find the span tag and move it up 40 pixels
  }, 250);
  $("#menu2 li").click(function() { //On click...
  $(this).find("span").stop().animate({ 
   marginTop: "-40" //Find the span tag and move it up 40 pixels
  }, 250);

 }   , function() { //On hover out...
  $(this).find("span").stop().animate({
   marginTop: "0" //Move the span back to its original state (0px)
  }, 250);
 }); 
});

Comment: Please have a look at my updated answer. Next time, be precise about the question you have and provide all the necessary information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** After seeing your link and reading the explanation, I would do it this way:

Create a CSS class `selected`:

```
.selected span {
    marginTop: "-40";
}
```

Add the class to the element on click and only perform the `mouseleave` action if the element is not selected:

```
$("#menu2 li").click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected').mouseleave();
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).find("span").stop().animate({ 
        marginTop: "-40" //Find the span tag and move it up 40 pixels 
    }, 250); 
}, function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).find("span").stop().animate({ 
            marginTop: "0" //Move the span back to its original state (0px) 
        }, 250);
    }
});
```

I created a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/jLEUh/) for you.

---

**Old answer:**

It should probably be:

```
function mouseEnterHandler {
    $(this).find("span").stop().animate({ 
        marginTop: "-40" //Find the span tag and move it up 40 pixels 
    }, 250); 
}

function mouseLeaveHandler() {
    $(this).find("span").stop().animate({ 
        marginTop: "0" //Move the span back to its original state (0px) 
    }, 250);
}

$("#menu2 li").click(mouseEnterHandler)
              .hover(mouseEnterHandler, mouseLeaveHandler);
```

Comment: so coooooool!big thanks to Felix Kling, you helps me a lot~that's what i want.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are talking about binding both the hover and click together. Try this:

```
$('#menu2 li').bind('click hover', function(){

// do stuff

});
```

Comment: This is neat, I would have created a separate function & bound it with both click & hover using the standard click & hover apis, but this is nicer. Didn't know we could do this. +1

Comment: -1 `$('sel').bind('hover', function(){/*...*/})` does not work (for all who want to know: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/jfHxj/). And even if, it would be the same as `$('sel').hover(in)` and not `$('sel').hover(in, out)`